# How to set defaults on custom widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I've created a custom jQuery UI widget. It looks something like this:

```
$.widget('wx.datetime', {
    options: {
        dateFormat: 'd-M-yy', 
        timezone: '', 
        ...
    },

    _create: function() {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Now how can I override those option defaults globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your widget, you're already specifying the set of global defaults:

```
$.widget('wx.datetime', {
    options: {
        dateFormat: 'd-M-yy', // These are the global defaults, change them here
        timezone: '', 
        ...
    },
    ...
 }
```

The default options can be overridden when creating an instance of your widget, like so:

```
$('#myDiv').datetime({
   dateformat: 'YYYY-mm-dd' // overrides defaults defined in widget
});
```

<strike>But if you do indeed need two sets of default options, the ones you've defined in your widget and some other set, you could use the built in jQuery.extend to merge the two sets of options inside of your create method:</strike>

```
_create: function( parms ) {
    $.extend(this.options, ( someGlobalOptionsObject || {} ));
}
```

To override the default options, set the `someGlobalOptions` to an object that has the same property names you want to replace.

Changing the properties in the `$.wx.datetime.prototype.options` object will allow you to specify different defaults for all new instances of your widget.

Comment: The options I've defined in the widget itself are the global default, but I might want to override them on a per-app basis (e.g. my different sites are for different geographic regions, so I want to set the timezone differently), however, I don't want to have to set on every single instance of the widget. You're saying jQuery UI doesn't have anything built in for `someGlobalOptionsObject`? There's nothing like `$.ui.datetime.options` that I could override?

Comment: [The docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/) actually say you can find the options in something like `$.ui.progressbar.prototype.options.value` but I can't find my widget under `$.ui`.

Comment: The options for your widget would be under your namespace. `$.wx` in your case

Comment: Aha! I didn't know that's how the namespaces worked. I only gave it one because it doesn't seem to work without. Thank you!